Does "every totally-ordered subset has an upper bound" imply "every directed subset has an upper bound" in $\mathsf{ZF}$?
Let $(X,\le)$ be a partially ordered set, and $S\subset X$ be a subset.
$\bullet$ $S$ is called totally-ordered (or a chain) if for every $x,y\in S$, we have either $x\le y$ or $y\le x$.
$\bullet$ $S$ is called a directed set if for every $x,y\in S$, there exists $z\in S$ such that $x\le z$ and $y\le z$.
$\bullet$ An upper bound of $S$ is an element $m\in X$ such that $x\le m$ for every $x\in S$.
So Zorn's lemma says: if a nonempty partially ordered set $X$ has the property that every nonempty totally-ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element.
In many applications of Zorn's lemma where the relation $\le$ is taken to be inclusion, like the existence of maximal ideals, the equivalent definitions of Noetherian rings/modules, and the existence of algebraic closure, we can actually show that for every directed family (rather than just for every totally-ordered family) of sets, their union of the desired upper bound. For example, if $\{I_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a directed familly of ideals of a ring, then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}I_i$ is also an ideal: for every $x,y\in\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}I_i$, suppose that $x\in I_i$ and $y\in I_j$ for $i,j\in I$, then $x+y\in I_k\subset\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}I_i$, where $k\in I$ satisfies $I_i\subset I_k$ and $I_j\subset I_k$. So I am interested in the strength of the following axiom in $\mathsf{ZF}$:

If a nonempty partially ordered set $X$ has the property that every nonempty directed subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element.

So a natural question is:

Question: Can we prove that in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that, if a nonempty partially ordered set $X$ has the property that every nonempty totally-ordered subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then every nonempty directed subset of $X$ has an upper bound?

If we assume Zorn's lemma then there is no problem: there is a proof using transfinite induction on cardinality of sets. But only in $\mathsf{ZF}$, such an argument could not work because not every set is equipotent to an ordinal. So what can we say about "every nonempty totally-ordered subset has an upper bound" and "every nonempty directed subset has an upper bound" in $\mathsf{ZF}$?

"lemma", not "lemme"

You probably meant $x\le m$ instead of $x\in m$.

Thanks! Both typo corrected.

No.
Suppose that $A$ is amorphous. That is, every subset of $A$ is finite or cofinite. One of the consequences of this is that every chain of subsets of $A$ is finite.
Consider the set of finite subsets of $A$, ordered under inclusion. Trivially, this is directed. Indeed, a lattice. Every chain has an upper bound, since every chain is finite. But as the whole set is directed, an upper bound would be a maximum, which doesn't exist.

Thanks, that's an interesting example! So I wondering if the strength of the modified Zorn's lemma (if a nonempty partially ordered set $X$ has the property that every nonempty directed subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element) has been studied?

You've weakened the condition, so now a broader class of posets satisfy it. In particular, all the posets which satisfy the old condition do. So, ZL holds...

Yes of course, silly me! I've got the wrong direction...

So you want to know "If every chain is bounded, then every directed set is bounded"?

No I mean... A chain is stronger than a directed set, so "every nonempty directed subset has an upper bound" is stronger than "every nonempty chain has an upper bound", hence I've strengthened the condition and weakened the axiom, no? I didn't get the direction wrong?

You are phrasing a consequence of AC which is stronger than ZL...

Sorry but as far as I've seen, this property is weaker than Zorn's lemma. Imagine that every nonempty chain of $X_0$ has an upper bound, then because what we have assumed is "if a nonempty partially ordered set $X$ has the property that every nonempty directed subset of $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has a maximal element", we cannot conclude directly that $X_0$ has an upper bound, simply because it is not necessary that every nonempty directed subset of $X_0$ has an upper bound.

It's not obvious, but Zorn's Lemma for trees is enough to prove AC. And in trees directed sets are chains.

That is an interesting result. Thanks!

It's easy to see when you phrase Dependent Choice as a statement on trees. But it's not an off the cuff thing if you're unfamiliar with all of that.
